# Removing a particular node on a specific line for all .xml files in a folder

Tags: python, linux, xml, xml-parsing

I would really appreciate if i can get help with this problem, I have got hundreds of .xml files in a folder lets say `/annots`, and each .xml has a node called `<occluded>0</occluded>` and I am basically trying to iterate through all the `.xml` files in the folder `/annots` and delete that node `<occluded>0</occluded>` from all of the files in the folder, or better still delete text from a particular line since the node `<occluded>0</occluded>`, appears on the same line for each file.

Heres what my .xml file looks like:
`

```
<annotation>
    <folder></folder>
    <filename>Glass217_jpg.rf.92a572df568fd3d2ce118bfb5ffa6cb5.jpg</filename>
    <path>Glass217_jpg.rf.92a572df568fd3d2ce118bfb5ffa6cb5.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>roboflow.ai</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>640</width>
        <height>640</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>Glass</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>55</xmin>
            <xmax>372</xmax>
            <ymin>248</ymin>
            <ymax>406</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

`

I havent been able to try anything else, as I am not sure there is any tool to help me with this. I am also expecting the file names to remain the same when the node has been deleted for each

Comment: ElementTree has an `Element.remove()` method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it by line number, you can simply use sed:

```
sed -i.bkp -e'19d' annots/*.xml
```

Will delete line 19 on all `*.xml` files in folder `annots`. The original files will be retained with `.bkp` suffix.

If you cannot rely on the line number, but want to parse the XML and delete the tag, `xmlstarlet` is your friend. Unfortunately, `xmlstarlet` does not have any in-place-editing option, so you need to run a loop:

```
for FILE in annots/*.xml; do 
        mv $FILE $FILE.bkp
        xmlstarlet ed -d '//occluded' $FILE.bkp >$FILE
done
```

Comment: `sed -i '/<occluded>0<\/occluded>/d' annots/*.xml` should remove all lines that contains `<occluded>0</occluded>`.